# NodeJS Bluebird Cheerio Web Scraper, Proper Indexing and Parsing of scraped data

Tags: promise, mapping, bluebird, cheerio, scraper

**Functional Overview**
I am scraping strings of thumbnail image URL data from an insecure site (http), downloading the images, and then uploading these images to a secure website server (https). I am using cheerio and bluebird to scrape list of *website URL's* using a mapped promise request, my code is shown below. I push the thumbnail URL image string data from the *website URL's* to an array stored in the "json" array and then write a file with the contained json data to a suppImages.json file.

**Current Issue I am trying to address**
Their is a variable number of thumbnail images (around 20 each) contained in the *website URL's* I am scraping. Right now, my code is set up to aggregate all the thumbnail image URL's into one array. What I would like my code to do is parse the specific thumbnail image URL's into separate arrays per *website URL*. So basically instead of the output looking like one blob of aggregate data from all the *website URL's* I want their to be several arrays each contained the discrete thumbnail images displayed on the given *website URL*.

**My code**

```
let fs = require('fs')
const requestPromise = require('request-promise');
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const suppURL = require('./output.json');

const urls = suppURL.urli;
console.log("Currently reading URLs from buttons of Realty Warp"+urls)

var json = { pictureThumb: []};

scraper = () => Promise.map(urls, requestPromise)
  .map((htmlOnePage, index) => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(htmlOnePage);
        var linksPic = $(".thumb img"); 

        $(linksPic).each(function(i, link){    
            var sop = $(this).attr('src');

        console.log("sop:" + sop)
            json.pictureThumb.push(sop); 

        });

        fs.writeFile('suppImages.json', JSON.stringify(json, null, 6), function(err){



            console.log('wrote file');

        })


        return console.log("URL"+index+':Scrape Complete');

  })
    .then()


    .catch((e) => console.log('We encountered an error' + e));

    scraper()
```

Comment: Isn't this bluebird stuff a little old-fashioned at this point?

Comment: This would likely be easier to do with an object used as a KV hash as the top-level data container -- each key would be a URL, and the value would be an array of images from that URL. May be possible with a set of arrays, but far more difficult to know which site gave which image without using a hash somewhere.